# Why are these fancy characters not shown in my prompt?

Tags: ubuntu, fonts, unicode, terminal-emulator

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04. On 14.04 I additionally installed Terminology.

On 16.04 Terminal and Terminology the characters in the bash are not displayed correctly:

[image: Terminology and 16.04]

Look with Ubuntu 14.04 Terminal

[image: Ubuntu 14.04 Terminal]

I first assumed that there are some environment variables that differ. I have not found which cause this. After I installed Terminology on 14.04 and it shows the characters the wrong way on 14.04 I assume it has nothing to do with the environment.

What do I have to configure to get the same result as with Terminal from Ubuntu 14.04 in the other options?

Value of `PS1`:

```
\[\e[37;1m\]\[\] \u \[\e[0m\]\[\]\[\e[0m\]\[\] \w \[\e[0m\]\[\]
```

Variables in Ubuntu 14.04 Terminal:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_ADDRESS=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_NAME=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8
```

And in Terminology on 14.04:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_ADDRESS=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_NAME=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8
```

Comment: Have you tried `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:enlightenment-git/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install terminology` ?

Comment: @JJoao I have used their ppa as described on the homepage of enlightenment and ran `sudo apt-get install terminology`

Comment: There's more than one thing that can go wrong: fonts and locale tables.  It would help if you reminded people of the string used in `PS1`.

Comment: It's "powerline", M. Dickey, and it uses several Private Use Area characters starting with U+E0B0.  This is an excellent example of the pitfalls of assuming that a Private Use is universal.

Comment: @ThomasDickey Added `PS1` to post

Comment: Have you set the terminal to use utf and a font that supports the relevant characters?

Comment: @terdon Added LAND* and LC_* env vars to question

Comment: @terdon Was the font. Totally forget that I once changes the font. Please make it an answer to get your credits

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That character (U+E0B0) is not a valid Unicode character. Or more exactly, it's in the [*private use* section in Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas), so you can use it for your own use.

In the example usage section, that Wikipedia article mentions:

> Powerline, a status line plugin for vim, use U+E0A0–U+E0A2 and U+E0B0–U+E0B3 for [extra box-drawing characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_characters).

Which leads us to https://github.com/powerline/powerline

Which gives [instructions on how to install fonts](https://github.com/powerline/fonts) for those Unicode point codes.

Comment: "" shows up as a right pointing arrow in every terminal (and in fact every application I've tried) _except_ terminology. I understand it is a private use code point, but why is terminology treating it different from everything else.