# How to get the arrow style bash prompt after installing powerline?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, colors, prompt, bashrc

I have installed powerline. But my prompt looks like so instead of arrow shaped:

[image]

In vim, it looks ok:

[image]

I have seen the issue here: https://github.com/powerline/powerline/issues/1697. But the solution there doesn't work for me.

There is a similar question but his question was to achieve it without installing powerline here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32443522/triangular-background-for-bash-ps1-prompt

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. How do I get it right?

Edit: I have tried the following ways:

1) Used powerline fonts but made no difference.

2) Installation was done using pip3. It was installed under python3.5 directory. Since it is not giving the desired result, I have uninstalled and installed it using pip. But the installation directory remained same i.e. python3.5 and the result also remained the same.  I then tried installing with `python2.7 -m pip install powerline-status` and it installed under python2.7 directory and it resulted in the same.

Comment: Is your terminal using a powerline font?

Comment: Yes I have installed powerline fonts. Specifically, I am using the source code pro for powerline.

Comment: There was a more similar question on _this_ stack exchange site at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/320735/ .

Comment: If you are suggesting to use patched fonts for powerline, yes I have tried that and they seem to make no difference for me. Also it seems he did not install powerline in the first place

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have fixed it by reconfiguring my locale.

I ran `locale` and it gave me this:

```
$ locale
LANG=en_IN.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_IN:en
LC_CTYPE="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

So I tried to set the following in .bashrc, but it didn't work:

```
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8   
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

So I ran the following and restarted the PC(Logging out wasn't enough):

```
sudo locale-gen en_US en_US.UTF-8
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

In the first configuration menu, I have deselected the `en_IN...` using spacebar and in next menu, I have selected `en_US.UTF-8`. After this `locale` showed all en_US.

Instead of all this, probably just setting `LANUAGE` and `LANG` to en_US in /etc/default/locale could have been enough? Idk

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is what worked for me in `Ubuntu 20.04` as well. By default, the locale was set to `en_IN` on my system.

Answer (score 2):

Install powerline fonts by cloning the repo (I'm cloning to a dir in home)

```
git clone https://github.com/powerline/fonts ~/powerline_fonts
```

Then link your desired font to your standard font directory. For example, if you've cloned the repo to a directory named `powerline_fonts` in your home, you'd use a command something like this.

```
ln -s ~/powerline_fonts/Anonymous\ Powerline.ttf ~/.local/share/fonts/
```

Set the preference of the terminal to use one of the powerline font such as "Anonymous for Powerline"

Now you should see the arrow shaped glyph.

---

Powerline uses special glyphs embedded in a font to render those nifty icons. So, you need a font that has those glyphs. Fortunately you can patch a font or use some already patched fonts like the ones from the repo I referenced earlier.

Comment: I have already installed powerline fonts and specifically using the source code pro for powerline in terminal. But I still don't get the arrow shape.

Comment: @vikramreddym Make sure you're using the right profile. There can be multiple profiles for a given terminal. Which terminal are you using?

Comment: It's a Gnome terminal I think. The default one on Ubuntu. I see that there is only one unamed profile in terminal preferences.

Comment: Did you set the font in profile? Which version it is?

Comment: Hello, yes I have set the font in the profile preferences. I have set it as "Source code pro for powerline regular" It's Gnome Terminal 3.18.3

Comment: @vikramreddym I know this may seems weird, but did you check the "Custom Font" is enabled in Terminal Profile preference? Also give the output of `fc-match "Source Code Pro for Powerline"`

Comment: Yes I have the custom font ticked. I get this output `Sauce Code Powerline Regular.otf: "Source Code Pro for Powerline" "Regular"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55617/discussion-between-anwar-and-vikramreddym).

Comment: FWIW you should just use the provided install.sh to install  from the repo.```git clone https://github.com/powerline/fonts ~/powerline_fonts && cd ~/powerline_fonts && ./install.sh```