# How to add image to Linux prompt?

Tags: linux, prompt, images

I was just watching a video and came across the below prompt
[image]

Seems like lightening image is at the first and some big arrow like structure to display the directory path. Do you know how to do this in putty please? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is implemented using some standard Unicode characters and some special Unicode characters used for [Powerline](https://powerline.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). This particular version looks like [the Agnoster `zsh` theme](https://github.com/agnoster/agnoster-zsh-theme). The characters involved are \u2699, 
±, , ➦, ✘, ⚡, ⚙.

You can adapt this to other shells and other terminals (such as PuTTY) by, on the one hand, changing your prompt setting (`PS1`), and on the other, configuring your terminal to use [a font with the appropriate characters](https://github.com/powerline/fonts). I’m not sure `ksh` supports the features required to get all the VCS features (branch indicators etc.), but you should at least be able to replicate the arrow.

See [Why are these fancy characters not shown in my prompt?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/320735/86440), [How to configure PuTTY to display these characters?](https://superuser.com/q/393834/414739), and [How to get the arrow style bash prompt after installing powerline?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/352426/86440) for more information.